# Symfony2: File Upload throws undefined property exception

Tags: forms, upload, doctrine, symfony

I want to perform an image upload with Symfony2.

I followed the cookbook entry but failed so I firstly used the fallback "upload directly in the controller" but here's the same issue.

I am getting

```
Notice: Undefined property:  Symfony\Component\Form\Form::$getData in
```

The controller isValid() part:

```
            if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

            $filename = uniqid('class_photo') . '.' . $photo->getFile()->guessExtension();
            $directory = __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/';
            $form['file']->getData->move($directory, $filename);
            $photo->setFile(null);
            $photo->setPath($directory . $filename);

            $em->persist($photo);
            $em->flush();
//....
}
```

Best Regards,
Bodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$form['file']->getData->move($directory, $filename);
```

Should probably be:

```
$form['file']->getData()->move($directory, $filename);
```

But I think you would be better off figuring out why the cookbook example did not work for you.  once a form has been validated you really should not need to go back in to it.

Comment: Hi,

I figured it out the issue was that I left $form->upload() in the controller even the entity now handles the upload